# twitter error on rails console while using twurl api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am trying to upload a media on twitter with below command from my rails console .

> ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(`twurl -H upload.twitter.com
>   "/1.1/media/upload.json" -d
>   "command=APPEND&media_id=1037245714940747777&segment_index=0" --file
>   /home/administrator/Downloads/s.mp4 --file-field "media" -t`) and
>   Getting the error-: JSON::ParserError: 822: unexpected token at ''

I am getting error of JSON parsning, Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `twurl` is like personalized version of  `curl` for twitter API. Run the command in your terminal and not rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's command is not for Rails console, it's for bash shell command line, you can just paste it to the Rails console and run. You can run it from bash shell:

```
$> twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -d "command=APPEND&media_id=1037245714940747777&segment_index=0" --file /home/administrator/Downloads/s.mp4 --file-field "media" -t
```

Comment: is there any way to upload our media from project using this twirl api in ruby on rails ?

Comment: `twurl` not suppose to be used with ruby on rails.

Comment: If you want to upload a media without rails, you can try this
`twurl -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json" -f ~/Downloads/file_name.jpg -F media -X POST`

Comment: But i want to upload video on twitter using rails. Please help!